# Comparing 2 datetime64[ns] dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two date columns namely date1 and date2.
I am trying to select rows which have date1 later than date2
I tried to

```
print df[df.loc[df['date1']>df['date2']]]
```

but I recieved an error

```
ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In either case, the idea is to retrieve a boolean mask. This boolean mask will then be used to index into the dataframe and retrieve corresponding rows. First, generate a mask:

```
mask = df['date1'] > df['date2']
```

Now, use this mask to index `df`:

```
df = df.loc[mask]
```

This can be written in a single line.

```
df = df.loc[df['date1'] > df['date2']]
```

You do not need to perform another level of indexing after this, `df` now has your final result. I recommend `loc` if you are planning to perform operations and reassignment on this filtered dataframe, because `loc` always returns a copy, while plain indexing returns a view.

---

Below are some more methods of doing the same thing:

**Option 1**
*`df.query`*

```
df.query('date1 > date2')
```

---

**Option 2**
*`df.eval`*

```
df[df.eval('date1 > date2')]
```

---

If your columns are not dates, you might as well cast them now. Use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df.date1 = pd.to_datetime(df.date1)
df.date2 = pd.to_datetime(df.date2)
```

Or, when loading your CSV, make sure to set the `parse_dates` switch on:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., parse_dates=['date1, date2'])
```